# How to get number of faulted messages from queue

Tags: azure, azure-storage

How can I obtain the count of faulted messages from a Windows Azure Storage Queue?

Comment: Which queue? Service Bus or Azure Storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about Storage queues, where a queue item reappears due to something going wrong while processing (meaning the invisibility timeout expired), each message has a DequeueCount (which, upon first get, is set to 1, then incremented with each additional get). There's no way to discover the total number of reappearing messages.

With Service Bus queues, you can set up a dead-letter sub-queue, letting you move messages to this dead-letter queue conditionally:

- expired messages
- max delivery count met

[This post](http://geekswithblogs.net/asmith/archive/2011/10/21/147398.aspx) has a good example of setting up a dead-letter sub-queue.